# Why does this proof that Every Well-ordered Set is Isomorphic to a Unique Ordinal need to use the Axiom of Replacement

Tags: set-theory, ordinals, axioms, well-orders

My question, please, relates to a proof that: *Every Well-ordered Set is Isomorphic to a Unique Ordinal* and the use of the Axiom of *Replacement* in it.

The proof begins letting $S$ be a well-ordered set. It then defines a set

> > $T=\{x\in S:\text{there exists an ordinal $\alpha$ such that $\alpha\cong S_x$}\}$

It then claims that for each $x\in S$, the ordinal $\alpha$ is unique by a prior result that no two distinct ordinals can be isomorphic as well-ordered sets.

Then by virtue of the Axiom of Replacement, the following is determined to be a set:

> > $\{\alpha:\text{$\alpha$ is an ordinal and there exists an $x\in S$ with $\alpha\cong S_x$}\}$

which it then goes on to show is an ordinal itself. And the proof proceeds on that basis once this is established.

My question is:

Why could you not just start with the second set to begin with, rather than define $T$ and invoke the Axiom of Replacement?

Thanks

Comment: how would you propose to prove it is a set?

Comment: The collection of all ordinals is not a set, so the second isn't a valid definition of a set. The existence of this collection as a *set* is due to replacement.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Thanks. Is that Burali-Forte?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The key problem in the absence of the axiom of replacement is that there may be well-ordered sets $S$ that are too large in the sense that they are longer than any ordinal. In that case, the collection of ordinals isomorphic to an initial segment of $S$ would be the class of all ordinals, which is not a set.

For example, with $\omega$ denoting as usual the first infinite ordinal, consider the set $V_{\omega+\omega}$. Recall that $V_0=\emptyset$, $V_{\alpha+1}=\mathcal P(V_\alpha)$ and $V_\lambda=\bigcup_{\beta<\lambda}V_\beta$ for all ordinals $\alpha$ and all limit ordinals $\lambda$. The set $V_{\omega+\omega}$ is a model of all axioms of set theory, except for the axiom of replacement. And indeed the theorem that every well-ordered set is isomorphic to an ordinal fails badly here: The ordinals in this model are precisely the ordinals smaller than $\omega+\omega$. However, all well-orderings of $\omega$ belong to $V_{\omega+\omega}$, and many are much longer than this bound (and much more is true, as $V_{\omega+\omega}$ contains plenty of uncountable well-orderings as well).

In this model, if you take as $S$ a well-ordering of $\omega$ of type $\omega+\omega$, then $T=S$, as each proper initial segment of $S$ has order type isomorphic to an ordinal smaller than $\omega+\omega$. However, the collection of ordinals isomorphic to an initial segment of $S$ is all of $\omega+\omega$, which is not a set from the point of view of the model. (And note that there is nothing difficult about finding an $S$ as indicated: Consider for instance the ordering of $\mathbb N$ where the odds and the evens are ordered as usual, but we make every odd number larger than every even number. To get a larger order-type, simply add an extra point on top of all of these.)

Of course, by taking as $S$ something longer, the problem is highlighted even more: Now $T$ is not all of $S$, and the collection of ordinals isomorphic to an initial segment of $S$ is again the class of all ordinals ($\omega+\omega$, in this case).

Maybe this illustrates how replacement avoids this problem: Suppose replacement holds (together with the other axioms) and we know that all ordinals smaller than $\omega+\omega$ "exist" (i.e., are sets). If $S$ is a well-ordered set of type $\omega+\omega$, then $\omega+\omega$ is the collection of ordinals isomorphic to a proper initial segment of $S$. Since $S$ is a set, then $T$ (which is a subclass of $S$) is also a set (in the case being discussed, $T=S$, of course). We know that each member $x$ of $T$ corresponds to a unique ordinal (i.e., there is a unique ordinal isomorphic to the initial segment of $S$ determined by $x$). By replacement, this means that the collection of all these ordinals is a set (it is the image of the set $T$ under the function mapping $x$ to the ordinal $S_x$ is isomorphic to). That is, $\omega+\omega$ exists as well.

If you examine the proof of the theorem you will see that the argument is essentially inductive: You go bit by bit ensuring that all initial segments of $S$, including $S$ itself, correspond to some ordinal. The proof, however, is usually not organized as an induction. Rather, you start with $S$ that is well-ordered. You extract $T$ from $S$ and note it is a (not necessarily proper) initial segment of $S$. You use replacement to conclude that there is a set of ordinals associated to $T$ as indicated. You argue that since $T$ is an initial segment of $S$, then this set of ordinals is also an ordinal, call it $\alpha_T$, which leads you to the conclusion that $T$ is order isomorphic to $\alpha_T$. Now you conclude that $T$ is indeed $S$, and you are done. The point is that if $T$ is not $S$, then $T=S_y$ for a unique $y\in S$, and we just proved that $S_y$ is order isomorphic to an ordinal, namely $\alpha_T$, so $y$ would have been in $T$ as well, and we get a contradiction.

Comment: Thanks - a work of art to be studied.

Comment: My pleasure. Best regards,

Comment: Dear Professor - I was so irked (euphemism) that this answer received a downvote that I wanted to give it an additional bounty. I even flagged the moderators, but they really can't do anything about downvotes. I was waiting to accumulate a few more points which I now have. Being a bit confused by the system when I tried to do it here, I offered it to another otherwise worthy answer amongst your many. While I have strong feelings about stealth downvotes without any substantiation, I am especially adamant when it comes to esteemed participants such as yourself as they can only serve as (cont.)

Comment: discouragement, much to the detriment of users such as myself.

Comment: Dear @Andrew, many thanks. Don't worry much about the downvotes, they tend not to mean much. Your appreciation more than compensates such things.

Answer (score 3):

Andrés Caicedo's answer nicely describes the broader context of what's going on here, but he did not actually identify what is wrong with what you propose on a very basic level.  You ask why we cannot just take the set $$X=\{\alpha:\text{$\alpha$ is an ordinal and there exists an $x\in S$ with $\alpha\cong S_x$}\}$$ to begin with.  The answer is that not every collection is a set!  You have to prove that any set you want to refer to exists, using only the axioms of ZFC (or whatever other axiomatic system you are working with).  So *somehow or other*, you are going to need to prove that there exists a set $X$ whose elements are exactly the ordinals $\alpha$ such that there exists an $x\in S$ with $\alpha\cong S_x$.  If you want to do this without first showing the set $T$ exists and then using Replacement, the burden is on you to describe how you would prove that this set $X$ exists by some other means.

You might ask why the argument using $T$ does not face this same issue: how do you know that $T$ is a set?  But that is easy to justify: $T$ is defined as the set of elements of $S$ satisfying a certain condition, and since $S$ is a set we can use Separation to say that $T$ is a set.  This method is unavailable for proving $T$ is a set, since there is no obvious set we already know exists which $T$ is a subset of.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to provide such a nice, lucid explanation. With regards,